# Display productlist with categories wont show not coupled categories

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have 3 tables, products, categories and couple_product_category
I want all the products from the database with a string of coupled categories.
That works fine however, when I add a new product, which is not coupled to a category yet, wont be return.

I want the fastest way to prevent performance.
This is what I have for now:

```
SELECT 
   product.id, 
   product.product_name, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(productcategory.name SEPARATOR '; ') AS categories
FROM
   m_catalog_products AS product
LEFT JOIN 
   couple_product_category AS category
ON 
   category.product_id = product.id
INNER JOIN 
   m_catalog_productcategoy AS productcategory
ON 
   productcategory.id = category.category_id
GROUP BY 
   product.id
ORDER BY product.id, product.is_active ASC
```

This will result in something like:

```
ID  Name       Categories
--  ---------  ----------------------
1   Product A  Category A; Category B
2   Product B  Category C
```

However, if Product C is not coupled to any category yet, it should shows up like:

```
ID  Name       Categories
--  ---------  ----------------------
1   Product A  Category A; Category B
2   Product B  Category C
3   Product C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN m_catalog_productcategoy` instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
   p.id, 
   p.product_name, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(pc.name SEPARATOR '; ') AS categories
FROM m_catalog_products AS p
LEFT JOIN couple_product_category AS c ON c.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN m_catalog_productcategoy AS pc ON pc.id = c.category_id
GROUP BY  p.id
ORDER BY p.id, p.is_active ASC;
```